# How to convert GIS rasters into vector polygons?

Tags: d3.js, maps, gis, gdal, topojson

How to turn raster GIS files (tiff) into .json ?

[Bostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4241134) used [some JSON data](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4241134/readme-heatmap.json) to feed his [D3.geom.contour plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geom/contour). But how to convert a GIS raster, let's say a tiny 11px/15px tiff image, into a JSON.

Final .JSON code such: [EDIT: this is NOT the topojson format]

```
[
[103,104,104,105,105,106,106,106,107,107,106],
[104,104,105,105,106,106,107,107,107,107,107],
[104,105,105,106,106,107,107,108,108,108,108],
[105,105,106,106,107,107,108,108,109,109,109],
[105,106,106,107,107,108,108,109,109,110,110],
[106,106,107,107,107,108,109,109,110,110,111],
[106,107,107,108,108,108,109,110,110,111,112],
[107,107,108,108,109,109,110,110,112,113,114],
[107,108,108,109,109,110,111,112,114,115,116],
[107,108,109,109,110,110,110,113,115,117,118],
[107,108,109,109,110,110,110,112,115,117,119],
[108,108,109,109,110,110,110,112,115,118,121],
[108,109,109,110,110,111,112,114,117,120,124],
[108,109,110,110,110,113,114,116,119,122,126],
[108,109,110,110,112,115,116,118,122,124,128]
]
```

Note: .shp to .json: There is already [a tutorial on how turning shapefiles into lighter topojson](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/#converting-data), but not useful to here.

Comment: What do you mean by "lighter"?

Comment: .tiff files will likely be quite huge. I here ask how to convert raster (tiff) to json, then I can find the contour using d3.geom.contour. But the file size will also be an issue. Insights are welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you want to simplify your raster in the GIS program before converting it.

Comment: I will likely need both indeed. I may do the simplification in my GIS software. But how to convert the raster into JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly, it's probably a several step process:

## Process

### Convert `.tiff` -> `.shp`

```
gdal_contour -a elev input.tif output.shp -i 10.0
```

### Convert `.shp` -> `.json` (*topojson*)

```
topojson input.shp -o output.json
```

## Resources

- Be aware of [TopoJSON Command Line](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) ;
- [Tutorial: Working with Terrain Data in QGIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20190211172944/http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com:80/2012/03/working-with-terrain-data-in-qgis.html) point out to GDAL utilities ;
- [`gdal_contour`](https://gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) builds vector contour lines from a raster elevation model.

Comment: Your answer is indeed helpful. I'am however looking for a direct solution where js process the .tiff file.