# convert .tif to geojson without gdal

Tags: api, gdal, geotiff

## Hi, I am working on an api with geotiff and geojson files. Do you have a way to use geotiff.py to convert an image file (.tif) to geojson without using GDAL?

## Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried to create this api (unfinished) but I don't have much knowledge of non-GDAL uses. *use python*

```
@app.route("imgeo/upload-img.html")
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        geo_tiff = GeoTiff(tiff_archivo, as_crs=none, banda=1)
        zarr_array = geo_tiff.read()


def server_info():
    ubication = [
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
                {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [-74.006393, 40.714172]  # for example
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "your ubication",
                        "description": "your ubication"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    return jsonify(ubication)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the application
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Totes noob here but I think this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207478/how-to-convert-gis-rasters-into-vector-polygons